# OpenGL crash just by removing std::cout<<"hi"<<std::endl from the program

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I have found very mysterious problem where I commented **out** the debug line I have in program and the program "segmentaion fault (core dumped)".

I narrowed down the program and come to this. This is the whole code that reproduce the problem :

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

#include <highgui.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_ALPHA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);
  glutInitWindowSize(500, 281);
  (void) glutCreateWindow("Alpha Test");

  cv::Mat image = cv::imread("alphatest.png");
  int texWidth = image.cols;
  int texHeight = image.rows;
  GLuint texId;
  glGenTextures(1, &texId);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);

  //std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;

  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texWidth, texHeight, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.ptr());
}
```

This program crash at `glTexImage2D` with error message:

```
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./mystery
```

(The program has been named mystery)

By uncommenting the `cout` line, the program runs fine without error along with message "hi". I wonder why I have to keep the debug line?

And this is alphatest.png
[image]

Comment: after `glut` inits you should create valid rendering opengl context and initialize `glew` function pointers by calling `glewInit()` before any `gl` calls.

Comment: @ampawd: glTexImage2D is a function from old days. It's been around since OpenGL-1.0. It most certainly does not require GLEW.

Comment: @datenwolf yeah, but before he calls some modern gl functions `glGenTexture` `glBindTexture` which requires `glew` initialization to correctly work.

Comment: @ampawd: That's wrong. Texturing was introduces in OpenGL 1.1 and is (at least on Windows) available from the opengl implementation directly.

Comment: @ampawd: None of the functions OP calls are modern OpenGL functions. Also GLEW is not the only extension loader around and for all we know OP could very well be using a loader wrapper library that links in lieu of `libGL` or `opengl32` and does all the extension loading transparently. The problem clearly is not related to not initializing OpenGL or failing to load extension pointers. Most likely it's a misaligned read access or buffer overrun due to the memory layout of `image` not matching what OpenGL tries to read from it.

Comment: @datenwolf just noticed he didn't even include `glew`. well, and I haven't said that glew is the only solution to load modern gl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely your image row alignment does not meet default settings at which OpenGL does read images (4 byte row alignment). This may cause OpenGL to read from an unmapped page, causing a segfault. When doing that iostream output that may create a page allocation, adjacent to the image buffer so that this problem remains "hidden".

Test this:

```
glGenTextures(1, &texId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);  /* tightly packed*/
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0); /* tightly packed*/
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);   /* tightly packed*/
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);   /* tightly aligned*/
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texWidth, texHeight, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.ptr());
```

Furthermore if your image is grayscale, then reading a GL_BGRA format will expect more data than imread delivered. You should not hardcode these parameters, but determine them from the image file as imread returns.

Comment: It's true! My image has only one channel so the read is wrong. And thanks for iostream explanation!!